# Laravel belongsTo and hasMany relationship working logic

Tags: php, model, eloquent, relationship

i have a 2 model right now. One for productCategory second is productType

i am trying to do this.

1. category1

   - Type1
   - Type2
2. category2

   - Type3
   - Type4
   - Type5

But something goes wrong and result is looking like that:

1. category1

   - Type1
   - Type2
   - Type3
   - Type4
   - Type5
2. category2

   - Type1
   - Type2
   - Type3
   - Type4
   - Type5

I made this in my productType Model:

```
public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class,'product_categories_id', 'id');
    }
```

and view look like this:

```
@foreach($types as $type)
    <a href="#">
        <li class="li">
            <h3>{{$type->category->name}}</h3>
        </li>
    </a>
    @endforeach
```

What should i do? I don't get it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT SQL:

product_categories: id, name, order
product_types: id, product_categories_id, name, order

Comment: the relationship between productType and productCategory is Many to Many right?

Comment: one to many sir.

Comment: can you post SQL tables ?

Comment: question updated.

Comment: try `return $this->belongsTo(ProductCategory::class, 'id','product_categories_id');`

Comment: Please post more of your view code.